# How to calculate $\oint_{\left | z \right |=3}^{ } \frac{dz}{\left ( z^{2}-4 \right )^{200}\left ( z-15 \right )^{2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

How to calculate $$\oint_{\left | z \right |=3}^{ } \frac{dz}{\left ( z^{2}-4 \right )^{200} \left ( z-15 \right )^{2}}$$    using Cauchy Integral theorem, formula or Residue theorem.

Edit: $z$ is complex number

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: It is a challenge question (for my class) which has been in the last year final exam :(

Comment: Because there are problem at z=2, z=-2, z=2i, z=-2i so I use residue theorem at these 4 point which i got to do derivative 199th order something like that. Am I using the theorem wrong? Sorry for my English

Comment: There are no problems at all at $\;\pm2i\;$ ...there **are** problems at $\;\pm 2\;$ , though.

Comment: My bad. You are correct, only z=2 and z=-2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: the sum of **all** residues is zero. (Why?) It might be easier to compute the residue at $z=15$ instead of the ones at $z=\pm 2$.

Comment: Why would anyone want the residue at $\;z=15\;$ in this case?

Comment: The integral is over the circle of radius 3.

Comment: @Timbuc By computing the residue at $z=15$ you also get the sum of the residues at $z=\pm 2$.

Comment: Neat trick you got there!

Comment: Is the fact that the residues sum to zero due to the parity and the fact that the poles are real?

Comment: How? My brain cannot follow.

Comment: @ThibautDumont Integral over a huge circle is zero because of the degrees. (Or by referring to the general theorem quoted by Daniel below.)

Comment: @ThibautDumont No, that's general. The sum of the residues of any meromorphic function on a compact Riemann surface is $0$.

Comment: @mrf Ah, of course! Very nice, forgot of that completely. Pretty cute, and I leave my answer just to show how terrible can it get if you don't take into account this. +1

Comment: So is it something like this: I integral over huge circle which is equal to zero which also equal to residue at $z=15$ plus residue at $z\pm 2$ and ta da! Right?

Comment: @co2netto Yes. Tada, indeed!

Comment: @mrf OMG! Thank you very much man!

Answer (score 0):

Let$\;C_1\,,\,\,C_2\;$ be tiny circles (say, radius$\,<0.1$) around $\;z=-2\,,\,z=2\;$  resp., then

$$\oint_{|z|=3}\frac1{(z^2-4)^{200}(z-15)^2}=\oint_{C_1}\frac{\overbrace{\frac1{(z-2)^{200}(z-15)^2}}^{:=f(z)}}{(z+2)^{200}}dz+\oint_{C_2}\frac{\overbrace{\frac1{(z+2)^{200}(z-15)^2}}^{:=g(z)}}{(z-2)^{200}}dz$$

Thus, you integral's value, by Cauchy's Integral Theorem, is

$$\frac{2\pi i}{199!}\left[f^{(199)}(-2)+g^{(199)}(2)\right]$$

Good luck now calculating those derivatives, but probably some recursion is due here.

**mrf's answer is the way to go here, and the above must be taken as the punishment of those that won't remember that very nice fact!**

Comment: Yes, my teacher tells me exactly something like if you do it straightly, you need to do 199 derivative. So I think there maybe some way that doesn't need to do 199 derivative

Comment: @co2netto Yes indeed...and you do **need** to check mrf's answer!